# How to "response" with a generated file without freeze the page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, download, freeze

I'm facing a problem with ASP.NET and Response.

What I want to do is really simple: button click, file generation, file download.

I can achieve this but whenever I try to click the same button (or another button) the page seems freezed: no postback, no event..

How can I return a file without freeze my page?

The code I'm using is something like that:

```
    var xls = GridViewExportUtil.Export((IEnumerable<ConfigurationReportSummary>)table.DataSource, "WebSiteConfig.xls");
    this.Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel";
    this.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", @"Attachment; filename=""WebSiteConfig.xls""");
    this.Response.Charset = string.Empty;
    this.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    this.Response.BinaryWrite(xls.ToArray());
    this.Response.Flush(); //Also tried without this
    this.Response.End(); //Also tried without this
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You Flush and End your Response, that's why your Page looks like its freezing. 
Create a handler, an ashx for example, to create and deliver the download. From your initial Page, link to that handler. That way, the Page can stay active.

For elaborate file delivery, try [this article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533).